# Linking platform libraries in Xcode OS X projects

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, dylib

I have an OS X application, minimum target is 10.9. I need to link against libcurl.4.dylib, which I can do, as this is included in the 10.9 SDK. I want to be able to deploy on other 10.9+ machines, but the the linkage to the library in the application is specific to my file system. I know I can use a build script and use otool to fix this path, but since this is part of the 10.9 platform, isn't there a better way to specify that this native library is required on the target machine, but not by copying as a bundle resource?

Comment: So, I just tried the build script/otool approach, which works with libraries that I build, but in this case the libraries in the platform SDK are stubs, and so I get an error: ...is Mach-O dynamic shared library stub file and can't be changed.

Comment: Nobody? I hear crickets..